# Quantity of flowing water in a 1000 m PE pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have a 1300 m PE pipe with 0.1 m diameter.
The starting point of pipe the pressure is 0.4 bar (40,000 Pascal), and the end pressure is 0 bar

My question is: How can I calculate the quantity of flow?

My initial thought is that the pressure drop is equal to starting pressure, I only need to read the flow from the pressure drop chart, but maybe I forget something.

The pressure drop chart is here:
[image: Text]

Comment: Do you mean pressure above that of ambient atmospheric pressure? 0 bar is hard vacuum.

Comment: Of course, both pressure values are above of atmospheric pressure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your first plot, adjusted the contrast so that I could read the log-log scales, and found that for a 0.1 m diameter pipe with a pressure drop of 30.77 Pa/m, the flow rate was about .0042 $m^3$/sec.Note that on that log-log plot, each dim line represents an increase of 1 (times a power of ten).(Example: you go from .001 to .002)

Comment: I understand this plot, I wasn't sure that this answer is so simple, I thought, I forget something.

Comment: So the pressure drop is equal to pressure of the starting point .

Comment: Only if the height is the same at start and end. If there’s a change in elevation, that will account for part of the change in pressure.